# How to disable Jqgrid disable while loading ?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

When my grid is loading data from server (the Loading box is showed) but the gird is still enable for effect.

Some one please help me to disable grid on loading process. Tks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [loadui: block](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) jqGrid option.

Comment: Further more, can u show me how to retrieve grid's status in meantime